# How to execute fewer lines of code in a whole spark script without rerunning the whole script again just like in Spyder-Python

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql, spyder

Hi I am using IntelliJ IDE for executing Spark/Scala code and it is independent of hadoop cluster. The Spark version that I have is 2.1.0

I have created around 100 lines of code and whenever I make even any small changes to the code, I have no other option but to run the whole code again.

Is there any way to execute the modified part of the code alone. I understand it means that the execution results of previous code contents should be in memory but is there any IDE or way to achieve this just like we can do in Spyder IDE for Python code ?

Any Scala IDE that enables us to do this or any way to do this in IntelliJ IDE will do my purpose.

Appreciating your help. Thanks

Comment: Use the REPL maybe?

Comment: @philantrovert do you mean we have to use the Spark shell ?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds the right thing to do if you're going to test something repeatedly with different changes. You can use the `:paste` and just paste the entire code to compile in one shot from your IDE.

Comment: Thank you @philantrovert . Please provide the same as an answer. Let me wait for few more answers. It would be good if I can achieve this in IDE itself.